# How to add an User Content through Sensenet Client?

Tags: sensenet

I want to add an User Content of Sensenet from a client which developed by .NET.

Please give me a solution.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create users the same way as any other content, by providing the parent, the content type name and a few *mandatory fields*.

The example below assumes that you already [initialized the client](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Client_library#Initialization), you have the */Root/IMS/MyDomain/MyOrgUnit* in your repo and there is no existing user there with the same name.

```csharp
var user = Content.CreateNew("/Root/IMS/MyDomain/MyOrgUnit", "User", "johnsmith");
user["LoginName"] = "johnsmith"; // best practice: same as the content name in the line above
user["Password"] = "123456789";
user["FullName"] = "John Smith";
user["Email"] = "johnsmith@example.com"; // this has to be unique under the domain
user["Enabled"] = true; // to let the user actually log in
await user.SaveAsync();
```

Let us know if you encounter any errors.

Comment: Cool, please mark the answer as correct so that others know too, thanks :)